# Image map in Flutter

Tags: image, dart, flutter, interaction

I'm trying to implement something along the lines of the following image, where every segment would have a click and an onDragEnter:

[image: Plutchik's wheel of emotions]

What would be the best way to implement this in Flutter?

Comment: `GestureDetector.onPanUpdate` ?

Comment: @pskink On top of a canvas? I'm new to Flutter, so I don't know if I want to draw this all on a canvas, on top of an image, or using widgets...

Comment: it does not matter if on canvas, image or something else - do what is easiest to you